# Using Stripes, what is the best pattern for Show/Update/etc Action Beans?

Tags: java, stripes

I have been wrestling with this problem for a while. I would like to use the same Stripes `ActionBean` for `show` and `update` actions. However, I have not been able to figure out how to do this in a clean way that allows reliable binding, validation, and verification of object ownership by the current user.

For example, lets say our action bean takes a `postingId`. The posting belongs to a user, which is logged in. We might have something like this:

```
@UrlBinding("/posting/{postingId}")
@RolesAllowed({ "USER" })
public class PostingActionBean extends BaseActionBean
```

Now, for the `show` action, we could define:

```
    private int postingId; // assume the parameter in @UrlBinding above was renamed
    private Posting posting;
```

And now use `@After(stages = LifecycleStage.BindingAndValidation)` to fetch the `Posting`. Our `@After` function can verify that the currently logged in user owns the posting. We must use `@After`, not `@Before`, because the `postingId` won't have been bound to the parameter before hand.

However, for an `update` function, you want to bind the `Posting` object to the Posting variable using `@Before`, not `@After`, so that the returned form entries get applied on top of the existing Posting object, instead of onto an empty stub.

A custom `TypeConverter<T>` would work well here, but because the session isn't available from the `TypeConverter` interface, its difficult to validate ownership of the object during binding.

The only solution I can see is to use two separate action beans, one for show, and one for update. If you do this however, the `<stripes:form>` tag and its downstream tags won't correctly populate the values of the form, because the `beanclass` or `action` tags must map back to the same `ActionBean`.

As far as I can see, the Stripes model only holds together when manipulating simple (none POJO) parameters. In any other case, you seem to run into a catch-22 of binding your object from your data store and overwriting it with updates sent from the client.

I've got to be missing something. What is the best practice from experienced Stripes users?

Comment: Well, since the flow of information is different for a show than for an update I've never thought of integrating them. They're always separate actions in my head.

Comment: That follows the idea that each Action is a verb and should be separate, but it doesn't feel very DRY. it seems to result in a lot of  duplicate code.

Comment: The key is fixing the problem that keeps your TypeConverter from getting to an open database session.  Use an Intercept to create (and later commit/rollback) a database session context that can be accessed from the thread.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, authorisation is orthogonal to object hydration. By this, I mean that you should separate the concerns of object hydration (in this case, using a `postingId` and turning it into a `Posting`) away from determining whether a user has authorisation to perform operations on that object (like show, update, delete, etc.,).

For object hydration, I use a `TypeConverter<T>`, and I hydrate the object without regard to the session user. Then inside my `ActionBean` I have a guard around the setter, thus...

```
public void setPosting(Posting posting) {
    if (accessible(posting)) this.posting = posting;
}
```

where `accessible(posting)` looks something like this...

```
private boolean accessible(Posting posting) {
    return authorisationChecker.isAuthorised(whoAmI(), posting);
}
```

Then your `show()` event method would look like this...

```
public Resolution show() {
    if (posting == null) return NOT_FOUND; 
    return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/posting.jsp");
}
```

Separately, when I use Stripes I often have multiple events (like "show", or "update") within the same Stripes `ActionBean`. For me it makes sense to group operations (verbs) around a related noun.

Using clean URLs, your `ActionBean` annotations would look like this...

```
@UrlBinding("/posting/{$event}/{posting}")
@RolesAllowed({ "USER" })
public class PostingActionBean extends BaseActionBean
```

...where `{$event}` is the name of your event method (i.e. "show" or "update"). Note that I am using `{posting}`, and not `{postingId}`.

For completeness, here is what your `update()` event method might look like...

```
public Resolution update() {
    if (posting == null) throw new UnauthorisedAccessException();
    postingService.saveOrUpdate(posting);
    message("posting.save.confirmation");
    return new RedirectResolution(PostingsAction.class);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, however the additional check if "(posting == null)" is annoying. I feel you should be able to throw that exception at the setter. Especially since you will need to duplicate the check for each event handler.

Comment: As you are using clean urls (i.e. "posting/update/12313"), the extra `posting == null` caters for users typing in the url bar, or accidentally bookmarking "posting/update" (N.B., no postingId). Minor, but perhaps a slight point in favour.